# error 1045 access denied mysql when I deleted the root user

Tags: php, mysql

unfortunately I deleted mysql user and now I can't access mysql 
I tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489119/mysql-error-1045-access-denied
But it is not proper for me because I don't have any user for mysql even I uninstalled and install the mysql but I can't access mysql
what should I do?
I wanted to have phpmyadmin without login and I ruined the whole

Comment: Why would you do that? I think you're basically screwed and have to re-install MySQL.

Comment: I reinstalled the whole it is in linux but I really don't know why still I can't access the mysql

Comment: You really should read the documentation next time before trying…
http://www.phpmyadmin.net/documentation/#authentication_modes

Comment: You can reset the root user with [these steps](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html).

Comment: thanks but it is for reseting the password not the user I don't have any user to reset it